# Interact with a curve in a Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interaction

I would like to allow user interactivity similar to [this Javascript demo](http://raphaeljs.com/curver.html) in a Matplotlib plot.
I have a fairly good idea of how I can do this with a slider widget, but I would prefer direct interaction with the curve. What tools are available?
It does not have to be a web app, it can be a simple interactivity built into the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the better ways I've seen is to use the [mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io/examples/drag_points.html) library (github [link](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3), which does a pretty good job at embedding matplotlib into D3.js.

The upside is that interactivity comes from javascript.
The downside is that interactivity comes from javascript.

I take this as an example of Atwood's Law.

Comment: Looks promising. Have not heard of Atwood's law. Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Question: say the user modifies a curve in the plot; are there tools to allow for the new curve to be written back to a python variable (either the original one or a new one)?